# Make Javascript Skip Execution When User Returns to Main Page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JavaScript slide show that executes when the main web page is visited.  When the visitor clicks a link to visit another page (example: pricing) and returns to the main page, the javascript executes the slideshow again which can "get on your nerves" after awhile.

Is there a way to track a visitor during the session so that the main page's slideshow only executes that first time they visit the site?

Here is the code and the site is https://www.softechsystems.com

---

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fadeslideshow.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var mygallery=new fadeSlideShow({
          wrapperid: "fadeshow1", //ID of blank DIV on page to house Slideshow
          dimensions: [741, 218], //width/height of gallery in pixels. Should reflect dimensions
          of largest image

      imagearray: [
          ["images_iob/admin_panel_3a.jpg", "", "admin panel", ""],
          ["images_iob/admin_panel_2a.jpg", "", "admin panel", ""],
          ["images_iob/admin_panel_1a.jpg", "", "admin panel", ""]],

      displaymode: {type:'auto', pause:1000, cycles:1, wraparound:false},
      persist: false, //remember last viewed slide and recall within same session?
      fadeduration: 500, //transition duration (milliseconds)
      descreveal: "ondemand",
      togglerid: "",
      oninit: function(){
             --this.setting.totalsteps;
       }
    })
</script>
```

Bear with me, I am a low information newbie .. thanky ... Scott Sagnette

Comment: `document.referrer` or `window.sessionStorage` come to mind.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to approach this Scott, but the easiest way will be to leverage the browser's [localStorage <sup>**MDN**</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

sessionStorage is less than ideal here, as it can cause the effect to happen too frequently for user preference. For example, if the user opens a new tab, there will be a new session. If the user reopens the page, same deal.

So, if you want it to only happen upon first visit, or a relatively first visit (for example in the past week), you should use localStorage. Here is a good way to accomplish that:

```
(function(){
    var loadItem = localStorage.getItem('loaded');
    var daysToExpire = 7; // one week

    // If it was loaded in the past week, then this is 1 (true), if not 0 (false)
    var loaded = Date.now() - loadItem < 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * daysToExpire ? 1 : 0;

    if(!loaded) {
        var mygallery=new fadeSlideShow({ /*...*/ });
    }
})();
$(window).on("load", function () {
    $(function () {
        localStorage.setItem('loaded', Date.now());
    });
});
```

Comment: Basically a cookie.

Comment: @JavaScript - Cookies are used to store information that is coordinated with a database, or which is consumed by a server for analysis. This *only* lives in the client. See [Local Storage vs Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220660/local-storage-vs-cookies) for some more information on the topic.

Comment: Cookies have nothing to do with databases by defintion.

Comment: @JavaScript - Not sure what you are on about mate, but whatever you are having I would also like some.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **sessionStorage** to set a key with array of visited pages like below:

```
// get value of key if exists, to check if page was visited
sessionStorage.getKey('visited');

// set the visited pages     
sessionStorage.setItem('visited', 'welcome_page,pricing_page');
```

**Reference:**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: Hopefully this comment gets to you ... THANK YOU for your time and info.  Will try this Friday !!